# How do I show more than 1 result if they have the same rules in PHPExpertsystem?

Tags: php, oop, artificial-intelligence, expert-system

An expert system made in PHP shows what sound an animal makes given the right rules/conditions. Heres a [demo](http://demo.deadschool.com/phpexpertsystem/sample-animal.php)

How do I make it show more than one result if there are more than one animal with the same rules in the mysql database?

I installed the system in mysql(xampp) and was able to run it. I tried to analyze the functions in the classes folder but I'm having a hard time understanding it. Is there something I need to loop in the code on any of the files in the classes folder?

The system can be downloaded [here](http://www.deadschool.com/sites/default/files/page-files/phpexpertsystem-1.0.0.tar.gz). It uses mysql as a database for its rules.